# Loop through Spark Dataframe, save results and use results on the previous iteration

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

How can I loop through a spark dataframe, apply business logic and use the results in the next iteration. I'm moving a script from pandas/numpy to spark because of the amount of data we have to process in this job. The business logic we have is very complicated and I've been able to move it to spark. The issue I'm having is how can I carry the results from Group 1 below to group 2 to be used. Also, the problem isn't that simple, there are about 10 variables that depend on the past group that will be used in the current group's calculations. I've been thinking about maybe streaming in the groups and saving the results to a temp table of some sorts and then using the results on the next stream? Not sure how that would work yet. Any ideas?

[image]

For added Context:

I have a dataframe with a ton of logic implemented into it.There's a column from 1 - 20. I have defined a ton of logic for Group 1. I need to pass in those same tranformations with the calculations in place to the next group 2 and so on and so on. Is it possible to pass the dataframe to a function with outputs?

Comment: can you share the output, you are looking for

Comment: @Rahul added context